# How can i pass the namefmt parameter in a php ftp connection?

Tags: php, ftp, ibm-midrange

I need to connect via FTP to an as400 server.
The connection necessarily requires the NAMEFMT parameter to write.
How is it possible to insert the parameter in php ftp connection code?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to use a library that provides free communication to the FTP servers like https://github.com/lazzard/ftp-bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ftp_site` to send the `namefmt` command.

```
$ftp = ftp_connect('serverurl.com');
ftp_login($ftp, 'user', 'pass');
ftp_site( $ftp, "namefmt 1");
ftp_chdir( $ftp, "/home/steve");

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($ftp, ".");

// write directory listing to stdout
echo "<pre>";
foreach( $contents as $item )
{
  echo "$item\n";
}
echo "</pre>";

// change namefmt to 0.
ftp_chdir( $ftp, "/qsys.lib/qgpl.lib");
ftp_site( $ftp, "namefmt 0");

// get srcmbr named PROOF in QGPL/QRPGLESRC
echo "<pre>";
$result = ftp_get($ftp, "php://output", "qgpl/qrpglesrc.proof", FTP_ASCII );
echo "</pre>" ;
ftp_close( $ftp ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [ftp_raw](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-raw.php) command:

@**EDIT** after the @RockBoro comment

```
$fp = ftp_connect("as400.example.com");
ftp_raw($fp, "site namefmt 0");
```

Take also a look to this [comment](https://www.rpgpgm.com/2019/04/using-ftp-with-ifs-files.html#c2977545095760004860) of Anton Gombkötö:

> Anton GombkötöApril 3, 2019 at 7:37 AM
>
> To avoid the ugly 500 error message when issuing the "namefmt 1" (or "na 1" for short) against a non-i-FTP-server, use "locsite" in front of it.
>
> `> locsite na 1`
>
> `Client NAMEFMT ist 1.`
>
> vice versa, when using a non-i-client to communicate with an i, use  "quote site". So even when the client doesn't know anything about "site", it sends it.
>
> `ftp> quote site na 1`
>
> `250 Now using naming format "1".`
>
> `ftp>`

Comment: that should be ftp_raw( $fp, 'site namefmt 0');